# Fedora 31 LXC service failed to start "Failed to start FUSE filesystem for LXC"

Tags: lxc, fuse, lxd

I'm trying to setup LXD system for test environments on Fedora Desktop workstation but the LXD service just wont start because the dependency service LXC fails. After trying to start the `sudo systemctl start lxd.service` the error message `journalctl -xe` gives is:

```
Sep 25 09:51:52 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 
ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=lxcfs comm="systemd" 
exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=succ>
Sep 25 09:51:52 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 
ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=lxcfs comm="systemd" 
exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=succe>
Sep 25 09:51:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: lxcfs.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 25 09:51:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: lxcfs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The unit lxcfs.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 25 09:51:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start FUSE filesystem for LXC.
-- Subject: A start job for unit lxcfs.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- A start job for unit lxcfs.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 6287 and the job result is failed.
Sep 25 09:51:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Dependency failed for LXD - main daemon.
-- Subject: A start job for unit lxd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- A start job for unit lxd.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 6394 and the job result is dependency.
Sep 25 09:51:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: lxd.service: Job lxd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

I'm pretty lost with this. So far I have been following the following steps for installing and configuring: https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/ganto/lxc3/ but now I'm stuck with a service start failure. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the lxcfs service? How about uninstalling it?

If you do need that service you should focus on why it is not working. Check the output of these commands:

```
journalctl -u lxcfs.service
systemctl cat lxcfs.service
```

Look for the ExecStart option in the [Service] section and try to run that command manually. Does it show any error in the screen?

Regards,